# синтаксис powershell

Tags: powershell, синтаксис

Написал вот такой вот скрипт для запросов на serial порт

```
c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command {$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM7,115200,None,8,one; $port.Open(); $port.WriteLine( 'AT+CUSD=1,"AA180C3602",15' + "`r" ); start-sleep -s 5; $port.ReadExisting()}
```

когда запускаю по одной команде, по очереди все хорошо. Как только пытаюсь запустить все скопом вываливается ошибка синтаксиса, подскажите как поправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM7,115200,None,8,one; $port.Open(); $port.WriteLine( 'AT+CUSD=1,\"AA180C3602\",15' + \"`r\" ); start-sleep -s 5; $port.ReadExisting()"`

Comment: @PetSerAl оформишь в виде ответа?